# Window partitioning in pyspark to same row

Tags: python, pyspark

I am window partitioning based on key columns to sum sales across years and make seperate columns out of it, i am able to get what i want but i have repetitions, can some please help me solve this?

this is the code i wrote

```
df = df.withColumn('SALE_2018_Sales_OP', F.when(
F.col('calyear') == '2018', F.sum("net_sales_op_sum").over(Window.partitionBy("ZZA_TEXT4", 'calyear'))).otherwise(0))
```

this is the output i get

[image]

i want an output like this
[image]

any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your original dataframe looks like?

Comment: window aggregations/operations don't reduce the number of rows. It seems a `groupBy` would be more suited for your use case